# Training Keras continuously vs single iterations

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, gradient-descent

Is there any difference between training Keras models once for 64 epochs of 64 times for one epoch. 
How do gradients work in this case? How do they keep the history of previews operations in order to adjust momentum?

1)

```
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=64, verbose=False)
```

2)

```
for i in range(64):
    verbose = (i % 16) == 0
    if verbose:
       print(i, end='')
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=verbose)
```

Comment: No difference. A difference would appear if you changed the batch size. (Gradient descent is performed for each batch).

Answer (score 0):

There is no **significant** difference between these two, because 
`Model.fit()` is running `_fit_loop` method internally for the number of epochs (the source code at [`keras/engine/training.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py)), so it's like the difference between...

```
for i in range(64):
  j += 1
```

... and ...

```
 for i in range(64):
   for k in range(1):
     j += 1
```

But still they are not *exactly* equivalent because of things that keras does besides the training itself:

- The history of the training is lost in the second approach (`model.history`). You have to maintain it manually if you'd like to check the learning curve (often times you do).
- Both `X` and `y` are standardized before the loop (see `Model._standardize_user_data` method). In some cases, the overhead of standardization can be comparable to the training of one epoch, in which case you may slow down the process.
- The second approach however allows you to change the parameters for each epoch, such as the batch size or shuffling. Not sure if it's a big deal though.

By the way, if you simply want to print something before or after each epoch, use [keras callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/), e.g. `on_train_end()` callback method.